# How to do vertical mapping using Item Reader

Tags: spring-batch

I have a file as follows with no columns. This can be grow vertically. This is a file which gives exchange rates with respect to some currency. can we read this using an Item Reader in spring batch and map currency and rate?

USD, JPY, BGN, ...

1.2195, 133.38, 1.9558, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in reader for that in Spring Batch. Your requirement is not common and you need a custom `ItemReader` implementation.